# France Business Visa - Convention de Stage

Tags: france, paperwork

I am Indian applying for the Business Visa to France (~ 90 days) for a training at my parent company in France, I'm working for its subsidiary in India.

All my documents are verified by [VFS Application center](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/) & are produced to Consulate General of France, Bangalore. My application was kept on hold for nearly 15 days and now they've asked for convention de stage.

1. Is [this the right document](http://travail-emploi.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/convention_stage_tripartite.pdf)?
2. Is it mandatory to get it signed by French Authority (DIRECCTE)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document linked in the point 1 is a sample internship convention (convention de stage). This document is kind of contract briefly describing what you'll do during your internship, how much you'll get in compensation of those tasks, etc...

If the internship lasts more than 3 months, then you'll need to have it approved by the Direccte. If it less than 3 months, then the consulate will validate it.

More details can be found there :
https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F17312